# Information on Planetary Science PhD programs?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, graduate-school, undergraduate

APS has a catalog available with information on graduate school programs in physics. I was wondering if anything similar exists for planetary science?

So far I have been going through individual university websites and professor pages to find information which is time-consuming.

Comment: Have you tried Googling "planetary research graduate programs" and "planetary science graduate programs"? You get some useful information on the first page of links.

Comment: As I stated in the question googling "information on planetary science phd programs" only brings up individual university websites. Additionally, I already stated I have spent many hours looking through.

Comment: Also @aeismail please readn"Stack Overflow Isn’t Very Welcoming. It’s Time for That to Change" this is exactly what people are talking about.

Answer (score 1):

Catalogs of programs are a casualty of the internet age. Most schools would prefer to direct traffic to their individual sites, rather than have a short blurb in a larger publication—especially if it's something they have to pay extra to maintain.

As an example of this, the American Astronomical Association's Division of Planetary Sciences just [has a compendium of links to school websites](https://dps.aas.org/education/graduate-schools) instead of a catalog. If a group like that maintains only a set of web links, I doubt there's a larger catalog out there.